# a c++ program to out put numbers in a table using a for loop

Tags: loops

Consider the code given below if its output is :

```
12 16 20 24
15 20 25 30
18 24 30 36


 for(int i=start; i<=end; i++)

 for(int j=first; j<=last; j++)

  cout<<i*j;
```

What are th values of start,end,first and last?

Comment: I believe your question is still lacking a few information about the code you are trying to understand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a homework question that should be directed toward a classmate, professor, TA, or other local tutoring resource.

Comment: According to [help/on-topic], question about solving homework must show effort. Where are you stuck at -- specifically, do you understand what the code does? Can you construct a system of equation to solve for the 4 unknowns? Can you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

start => 4

end => 6

first => 3

last => 6

you can have done this of your own, if you have analyzed the output precisely.

First four terms are in table of 4 ranges from 3 to 6

followed by table of 5

followed by table of 6.

Please first try then put the question here.